# localhost:3000 page isn't working in prerender.io

Tags: angularjs, node.js, localhost, prerender

I am testing prerender in window 7. I have followed the steps given in [this](https://prerender.io/documentation) link. I have cloned project from git, run npm install and run server like

- node server.js

When I go to localhost:3000 , it shows localhost page isn't working. And if if run

http://localhost:3000/https://www.google.com/

It opens the actual google page with this url

https://www.google.com.pk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=yRwbWKLZIsnoUsvAiJAP

I have read about prerender that it ignores images and other graphics etc.

With localhost:3000 , I want to see result like

http://service.prerender.io/https://www.google.com

Comment: Is google checking your location from your IP address and redirecting you to google.com.pk? Are you seeing on the Prerender console that it returned a status code 302?

Comment: @Prerender.io I have the same problem,

Comment: I have also same problem